# why paramter in a route group is required in all sub resource route methods

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-routing

I have a route group that has a parameter like this :

```
Route::prefix('/website/{account}')->group(function () {
        Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], 
            Route::resource('/member', 'MemberController');
        });
    });
```

As you see there is a `account` parameter in route group.

Now to show `member-create` page I added this to `MemberController` :

```
public function create ($account)
        {
            return view('admin/pages/members/members-create',compact('account'));
        }
```

Now when I want to create a form that send request to `store` function of  `MemberController` like this (in `member-create.blade.php`) :

```
{!! Form::open(array('action' =>['MemberController@store'],  'id'=>'createMemberForm')) !!}
```

laravel says that :

```
Missing required parameters for [Route: member.store] [URI: website/{account}/member].
```

That's because, I must to add a `$account` parameter to `store` function. in fact beacause I used a parameter in route grouping, I have to always send a value as that parameter first to `create` function and then from there passe it to `store` function that, Naturally, this takes a lot of time from me.

Is there any way to solve this problem where $account parameter send to functions automatically or any alternate way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is easy way to send it automatically. You can obviously use:

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' =>route('member.store', ['account' => 'account_value']),  'id'=>'createMemberForm')) !!}
```

to pass valid value to route, if needed can create helper method but there's no other reasonable way to do it automatically. When you use parameter in route usually means you need so, so maybe you should consider if you really need it if you want to fill it automatically?